# Ionic lazy loading giving error "invalid link" for custom root module

Tags: ionic-framework, lazy-loading, ionic3

I am working with ionic v3.2.0 and as a part of requirement I have created another root component named as start.component.ts and start.modulue.ts. Which is a just copy of app.component.ts and app.modulue.ts.

I have implemented lazy loading in **appModule**.

**main.ts**

```
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = "LoginPage";

  ...
}
```

Everything is working fine and Login module is getting load.

No I changed to **startModule**

**main.ts**

```
import { StartModule } from "./start.module";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(StartModule);
```

**start.component.ts**

```
export class StartApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = "LoginPage";

  ...
}
```

This is giving me error like :

```
main.js:1436 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: LoginPage
```

**login.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage)
  ],
  exports: [
    LoginPage
  ]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

**login.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {
 ....
}
```

P.S. : If I remove LazyLoding, everything is working fine. And I have tried using latest ionic version 3.4.0, but same error.

Comment: make sure you have created `loginpage.module.ts` file in **LoginPage** folder

Comment: Yes it is there. I followed ionic guidelines and CLI to create a page. And although it is working when root module is appModule

Comment: can you show login page ts and module file.

Comment: You can see edited question.

Comment: Did you renamed app.module.ts and app.components.ts to start.module and start.components?

Comment: I have created brand new application and lazy loading with working fine

Comment: I didn't rename but I copied and paste and then did changes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147713/discussion-between-parth-hirpara-and-mumair).

Answer (score 0):

Solution rename your file from **start.module.ts** back to **app.module.ts**.

because when ionic start compilation it start looking for file named **app.module.ts** when it didn't find it in app directory; then generate warning and error similar to this

> The main app NgModule was not found at the following path:
>   C:\Users\muham\Documents\ionic-projects\todo\src\app\app.module.ts

Which means it is hard coded in ionic-cli for compilation process. So, application require file named `app.module.ts` in app to compile and build. 
Hopefully this will resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks, But actually I have both modules are there. start and app with module and component files.I come to a conclusion that, you can't run two root modules with lazyLoding in ionic 3. So I will use appModule and manage.

Comment: yes offcourse. Remove extra module and component files and rename your start.module.ts to app.module.ts

Comment: @parth.hirpara its not an alternative, it's by design: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12464